# Indexing slow on column which is not unique?

Tags: postgresql

Indexing slow on column which is not unique? There is a index for code and date columne but it is not unique. Average need 5 minutes to get data. How to improve it?

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE select * from timestockdata where code ='3182' and date>'2014-02-04'
"Bitmap Heap Scan on timestockdata  (cost=3300.94..359202.76 rows=106234 width=439) (actual time=734.561..86351.988 rows=127715 loops=1)"
"  Recheck Cond: (((code)::text = '3182'::text) AND (date > '2014-02-04 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))"
"  Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 2689023"
"  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on timestockdata_index  (cost=0.00..3274.38 rows=106234 width=0) (actual time=713.362..713.362 rows=127715 loops=1)"
"        Index Cond: (((code)::text = '3182'::text) AND (date > '2014-02-04 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))"
"Total runtime: 86476.266 ms"
```

http://explain.depesz.com/s/AnxT

```
CREATE INDEX timestockdata_index
  ON timestockdata
  USING btree
  (code COLLATE pg_catalog."default", date);
```

After set work mem to 100mb.

```
"Bitmap Heap Scan on timestockdata  (cost=3304.95..359206.77 rows=106234 width=439) (actual time=2653.288..933680.348 rows=127902 loops=1)"
"  Recheck Cond: (((code)::text = '3182'::text) AND (date > '2014-02-04 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))"
"  Buffers: shared hit=58 read=118695 written=37"
"  I/O Timings: read=931565.063 write=0.663"
"  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on timestockdata_index  (cost=0.00..3278.39 rows=106234 width=0) (actual time=2582.697..2582.697 rows=127902 loops=1)"
"        Index Cond: (((code)::text = '3182'::text) AND (date > '2014-02-04 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))"
"        Buffers: shared hit=2 read=1465"
"        I/O Timings: read=2399.675"
"Total runtime: 933817.470 ms"
```

result = 58117248

```
select count(*) from timestockdata
```

---

I have other trade detail table having total 73569274 record. This data is much larger than previous timestockdata table but can be settle in 11 seconds. The only different i think is because the timestockdata is save in not order format(save->code1,date.save->code2,date) where tradedetail table is save in order format(save->code1,date for entire day then only move to code2 for entire day transaction).

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE,buffers) select * from tradedetail where code='3182' and  date::date <'2014-02-04' order by date
"Sort  (cost=887351.99..888022.69 rows=268280 width=47) (actual time=11203.296..11237.917 rows=348740 loops=1)"
"  Sort Key: date"
"  Sort Method: external sort  Disk: 22496kB"
"  Buffers: shared hit=1 read=14085, temp read=2812 written=2812"
"  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tradedetail  (cost=30586.27..846656.01 rows=268280 width=47) (actual time=7070.147..10756.227 rows=348740 loops=1)"
"        Recheck Cond: ((code)::text = '3182'::text)"
"        Filter: ((date)::date < '2014-02-04'::date)"
"        Rows Removed by Filter: 412035"
"        Buffers: shared hit=1 read=14085"
"        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on tradedetail_index  (cost=0.00..30519.20 rows=804841 width=0) (actual time=7048.439..7048.439 rows=769686 loops=1)"
"              Index Cond: ((code)::text = '3182'::text)"
"              Buffers: shared hit=1 read=5766"
"Total runtime: 11265.853 ms"
```

Comment: A bitmap index scan on a single index? That's ... weird.

Comment: @CraigRinger, happens all the time on queries that return a lot of candidates from the index.  In fact, that is the common case in which I seem bitmap index scans used.  I rarely see `BitmapAnd` or `BitmapOr` in the wild.

Comment: [This](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/12553.1135634231@sss.pgh.pa.us) seems to be on point with respect to the optimizer's choice of a bitmap index scan.

Comment: @jjanes I guess it makes sense as a compromise between an index scan (lots of heap random i/o) and a seqscan for intermediate row counts. It's not something I've run into, at least not in parts of plans that have been of performance interest. I see BitmapAnd and BitmapOr much more often. Funny how that works out.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't actually need to retrieve 125,000 rows, rewrite the query so that it doesn't return that many rows.

Your bitmap heap scan looks like it is overflowing, requiring costly rechecks.  You could consider increasing work_mem to help that.

You could cluster the table according to that index, so that rows with the same `code` are physically adjacent.

You might benefit from more RAM and/or a faster disk array.

Also, `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE,buffers)` will give more useful information, particularly if track_io_timing is on.

Comment: i already set work mem to 100mb. result posted above. not usefull